# how to get value from specific key in MongoDB with Golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I write the code with Go to get value from specify key, but it's return only `_idà value
from my code

```
func main() {
    mongoDialInfo := &mgo.DialInfo{
        Addrs:    []string{"localhost:27017"},
        Database: "person",
        Username: "user",
        Password: "user",
        Timeout:  60 * time.Second,
    }
    session, err := mgo.DialWithInfo(mongoDialInfo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()

    c := session.DB("person").C("person")

    result := Person{}
    name := "Bill"

    err = c.Find(bson.M{"name": name}).Select(bson.M{"surname": 1 }).One(&result)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Surname is ", result)
}
```

and the result from code is

{ObjectIdHex("5b9bb0b39b5c3e5733e1c8f7")  }

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: Most likely you did not export fields of `Person`, or they have the wrong `bson` tag. Show us your `Person` type.

Comment: type (Person struct {
         ID        bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
         name string `bson:"name"`
         surname  string `bson:"surname"`
     })

Comment: As suspected, you must export your fields (start them with uppercase latter).

Comment: Thank you icza It's work now, sorry because I'm newbies to change from nodejs to golang with new project